# Using a "slider" to change crease on specific edge of subdivision surface modifier object

Tags: geometry-nodes, drivers, vertex-groups

I need to "connect" a slider (a constrained object) to the edge crease value of a vertex  group as shown in the attached image.

Is there a way (through nodes/drivers/scripting) that would accomplish this effect ?

[image: Moving slider affects MeanCrease of specific vertex group]

Comment: just with python, not with vanilla blender because mean crease cannot have a driver which is pretty clear because then the driver would also have to store somewhere which and how many vertices you mean.

Comment: I've already done it with python but need to run the script to do it. Is there a way to trigger the script on e.g. the movement of the "slider" ?

Comment: yes, you could e.g. call your python script by a "script expression" driver in your z-value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call any python function in Blender in a driver by doing this:

```
import bpy

def square(val):
   """Returns the square of the given value"""
   return val * val

# Add function to driver_namespace.
bpy.app.driver_namespace['square'] = square
```

Run the script and enter "square()" as expression in your driver. Then the function will be called and the return value is the driver value.

source:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/workflow_examples.html